# Return specific key (field) from fetch api response object

Tags: javascript

Fetching a word from this API(https://api.dicionario-aberto.net/random) gives me the whole object:

```
{
  "word": "linguaraz",
  "wid": 74891,
  "sense": 1
}
```

How can I get to return only the word value in this object?

This is my code:

```
const getWord = async function () {
    const response = await fetch ("https://api.dicionario-aberto.net/random?get.value")
    const words = await response.text();
    const wordArray = words.split("\n");
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordArray.length);
    word = wordArray[randomIndex].trim();
    placeholder(word);
};
```

Comment: You want to get only "word" field from Api's answer or get it from response object?

Comment: You api return nothing

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your api result into JSON first instead of text, then it will be easier to access word,
like this

```
async function getData(){
   res = await fetch('https://api.dicionario-aberto.net/random');
   data = await res.json();
   console.log(data.word);
}
getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert fetch data to json and read it as object property:

```
const getWord = async function () {
  const response = await fetch ("https://api.dicionario-aberto.net/random?get.value")
  const words = await response.json();
  placeholder(word);
};
```